# Add items to dict in elixir

Tags: dictionary, data-structures, iterator, elixir, scoping

I have a nested dict in elixir, from which I want to save the latest items in a new dict.

```elixir
sorted_slides = [
  %{
    id: 1,
    visual_events: [
      %{entity_id: 1, payload: "abc"},
      %{entity_id: 2, payload: "def"}
    ]
  },
  %{
    id: 2,
    visual_events: [
      %{entity_id: 2, payload: "yui"},
      %{entity_id: 3, payload: "def"},
      %{entity_id: 4, payload: "ghi"},
    ]
  },
  %{
    id: 3,
    visual_events: [
      %{entity_id: 2, payload: "ert"},
      %{entity_id: 4, payload: "poi"},
    ]
  }
]

dict = %{}

Enum.each(sorted_slides, fn slide -> 
  Enum.each(slide.visual_events, fn ve -> 
    eid = ve.entity_id
    dict = Map.put(dict, eid, ve)
    IO.inspect(dict)
  end)
end)

IO.inspect(dict)
```

My original data structure contains items that may be overwritten by newer items. I want the new `dict` to be:

```elixir
dict = %{
  1 => %{entity_id: 1, payload: "abc"},
  2 => %{entity_id: 2, payload: "ert"},
  3 => %{entity_id: 3, payload: "def"},
  4 => %{entity_id: 4, payload: "poi"}
}
```

I want the `dict` to save the changes made to it by each iteration, but I guess that scoping works different from some other languages here.

How would I achieve this in Elixir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Enum.flat_map/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#flat_map/2) to extract the inner elements, and [`Map.new/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#new/2) to construct a new map from those elements. `Map.new/2` will ensure the latest element prevails when there are duplicate keys.

```elixir
sorted_slides
|> Enum.flat_map(fn %{visual_events: items} -> items end)
|> Map.new(fn %{entity_id: id} = map -> {id, map} end)
```

Result:

```elixir
%{
  1 => %{entity_id: 1, payload: "abc"},
  2 => %{entity_id: 2, payload: "ert"},
  3 => %{entity_id: 3, payload: "def"},
  4 => %{entity_id: 4, payload: "poi"}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the case you want to build a structure within a "loop", you can most of the times reach for [`Enum.reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/3):

```elixir
Enum.reduce(sorted_slides, %{}, fn slide, acc -> 
  Enum.into(slide.visual_events, acc, fn event -> 
    {event.entity_id, event}
  end)
end)
```

The inner loop could be implemented with `Enum.reduce/3` as well, but [`Enum.into/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#into/3) makes it slightly more compact.

[`Enum.each/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#each/2) is only meant to perform side-effects (like printing) but doesn't return any actual result, it just always returns `:ok`.

> I guess that scoping works different from some other languages here.

Exactly, in Elixir you don't mutate existing structures, you create new structures and need to pass them around. This is typically the case of our `acc` accumulator above.

Side note: in Elixir, these are not called dicts but [maps](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html). There have been deprecated dicts structure [in the past](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Dict.html).

Comment: It might be helpful to demonstrate in code that you must re-assign the result of these operations, e.g. `modified_list = Enum.map(old_list, &some_func/1)` because as you've pointed out, in Elixir you cannot mutate existing structures: you have to create new ones.